# Java Gmail API Read Messages Error (400 Bad Request)

Tags: java, email, google-api

I'm a little confused to how the gmail api works for Google. Here is my authentication code for the `Gmail` service:

```
public static Credential authorize() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        InputStream p12 = GoogleUtils.class.getResourceAsStream("/key.p12");

        File file = new File("hi");
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.copy(p12, outputStream);
        outputStream.close();

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
       GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId(EMAIL)
            .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
            .build();
       file.delete();
        return credential;
    }
```

And here's the code for the specific service....

```
public static Gmail getGmailService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
            .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
            .build();
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get the `Gmail` service and then make an API call for all emails, but I don't know how to do that. This is the code of tried thus far:

```
public static void getEmails() {
    try {
        ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(GoogleUtils.EMAIL).setQ("from:fatalcubez@gmail.com").execute();

        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = service.users().messages().list(GoogleUtils.EMAIL).setQ("from:fatalcubez@gmail.com").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (Message message : messages) {
            System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

From what I've read, you can't use service accounts to send/receive emails. But, what I'm not sure is how to setup an account so that it can be used through the api to send/receive emails. Btw, this whole project is a standalone desktop app, no android or web stuff. I simply just want to read all emails sent to some gmail account, doesn't matter if it's one of my gmail accounts or a service account. I just can't seem to figure it out.

Oh, and here's the actual error I'm getting.

[image]

If you guys could point me somewhere that has a clear explanation on all of this that would be great (or if you have a clear explanation that would also be good :)). Thanks!

Comment: You cant give another user access to read your Gmail so you cant use a service account with gmail.  You need to use oauth2

Comment: So I need to authenticate another way? Specifically for the Gmail Api? Because right now that one authorize() method I'm using for both gmail and drive stuff, so I need the service account for the drive stuff.

Comment: You can use Oauth2 with drive as well unless you are uploading to the service account drive account